# C++ "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error

Tags: c++

```
void Sort(Maximumas Maxi[], int ind){
    int m = 0; // begin
    bool bk = true;
    while(bk){
        bk = false;
        for(int j=ind-1; j>m; j--){
            if(Maxi[j].GetQuantity() > Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity()){
                bk = true;
                int c = Maxi[j].GetQuantity();
                Maxi[j].GetQuantity() = Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity();
                Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity() = c;
            }
        }
        m++;
    }
}
```

When  I try to compile this code I get an error:
**expression must be a modifiable lvalue**

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: On which line?  What is the definition of `Maximumuas`?

Comment: check this Maxi[j].GetQuantity()=..

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Well, you used a expression not being a modifiable lvalue when one was expected by the compiler, doncha think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that `Maximumas::GetQuantity()` returns by value or `const` reference, so you cannot do this kind of thing:

```
Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity() = c;
```

You need an overload that returns a reference. Assuming it returns `int`, you need something like

```
int& GetQuantity();
const int& GetQuantity() const;
```

where the `const` overload allows you to call the member on `const` instances or via `const` references.

Note that unless this is an exercise, it would be simpler to use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable predicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to have the signature of `Maximumas::GetQuantity()` to be sure, but it looks like this method returns a non-modifiable type, so that you can't assign a value to it, e.g. `int` or `const int&`. 
This would explain why the two following lines fail:

```
Maxi[j].GetQuantity() = Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity();
Maxi[j-1].GetQuantity() = c;
```

You should change your method to return a modifiable type, like `int&`, to make it work.